# How to use variable in HTML img src path

Tags: html, django

I have the following in an HTML template:

```
<img src="{% static 'display/plots/AAPL.png' %}" alt="">
```

I also pass a variable called `ticker`. How can I use it instead of AAPL?

Comment: I assume your using Django as that's where the `{% %}` template tags will be recognized. I would recommend adding that tag to your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what template framework you are using, as that is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a variable that stores the image filename named `ticker`. You can just render the variable in your template using `{{ ticker }}` along with the `static` call tag. Utilizing the template variable with the image filename to replace "AAPL".

Since `static` doesn't play nicely with template tags `{{ }}` inside of it's argument. Here is one way to accomplish what you seek using `get_static_prefix` along with the template variable data.

```html
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}display/plots/{{ ticker }}.png" alt="">
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I get the following when inspecting the code: `<img src="/static/display/plots/%7B%7B%20ticker%20%7D%7D.png" alt="">`

Comment: Ah, yes the `static` call tag doesn't play nice with template tags inside it's parameter. Let me update my answer, I know a way that works.

Comment: Your welcome! I'm glad to have helped. Happy coding!